# NeoVim: How to move the cursor to a window by its window number?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

As title. After doing `windo` it seems like Vim forgot where it started.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that NeoVim provides some functions to do so easily:

```lua
local cur_win = vim.api.nvim_get_current_win()
-- do your windo, for example:
vim.cmd("windo if &buftype != 'nofile' | let g:non_float_total += 1 | endif")
vim.api.nvim_set_current_win(cur_win)
```

And since my problem was originally asked in context of Vim before edit(yeah, it's embarrassing that I'm writing NeoVim plugin in Lua but always resort to VimScript first :p ), here is an answer that resolves that, by the power of ancient great people:

> " Just like windo, but restore the current window when done.
>
> ```
> function! WinDo(command)
>   let currwin=winnr()
>   execute 'windo ' . a:command
>   execute currwin . 'wincmd w'
> endfunction
> com! -nargs=+ -complete=command Windo call WinDo(<q-args>)
> ```

The source: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Windo_and_restore_current_window

Comment: The answer to the title question is basically `:execute winnr 'wincmd w'` aka `:call win_gotoid(win_getid(winnr))` where `winnr` is the desired window number. Window IDs are sometimes better, though.